# Should I use new or edit action on model that inherits from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, devise, sti

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Teacher < User 
end

class Student < User 
end
```

Users login in through a devise form that creates a user. I want to have two kinds of profiles like teacher and student though and they can be both at the same time as well.

So when I go to create a new Teacher I am just going to `teachers/id/edit` form and updating the teacher that inherits from user. Should I do this or can I go to `teacher/new` ? and create a teacher from there when I have my models inherit like I do?

Comment: http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: usecase is not totally clear. please be more specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use inheritance here. Create separate `TeacherProfile` and `StudentProfile` tables, and make one-to-one associations:

```
class TeacherProfile
  belongs_to :user
end

class StudentProfile
  belongs_to :user
end

class TeacherProfile
  has_one :teacher_profile
  has_one :user_profile
end
```

Then just follow the standard protocol. Go straight to `edit`, check if the profiles exists, and create it if it doesn't, something like this:

```
def edit
  @profile = TeacherProfiler.where(user: current_user).first_or_create
end
```

Comment: I was recommended by others to use inheritance. How do I decide?

Comment: Heh, that's your decision. You can look similar question for more thorough answer/discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010998/users-attributes-depend-on-users-type-best-way-to-implement-in-rails/32011658?noredirect=1#comment51990543_32011658